# How to Add Attribute Terms Image in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I have created an attribute "Brand", and added some terms, like "Brand One", "Brand Two" etc..
I want to add an image for each term.
Right now there is no option to add image in attribute terms.

Please tell me how to add image in attribute terms.

An admin link is like this:

```
 .../wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=pa_brand&post_type=product'
```

Answer (score 5):

WooCommerce stores product attributes outside of the usual taxonomy table, so you'll need to go with something more WC-specific. Try the [Variation Swatches and Photos extension](http://www.woothemes.com/products/variation-swatches-and-photos/).

**UPDATE:** You *can* use the [Taxonomy Images plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) but you have to make a minor alteration. By default the plugin only displays taxonomies that are set to display in the admin area (i.e. the `show_ui` value is set to true). WooCommerce hides the product attribute taxonomies by default, so the plugin will not display them in the settings screen. You can change this behaviour by commenting out/deleting lines 402-402 of `taxonomy-images.php`:

```
    if ( ! isset( $taxonomy->show_ui ) || empty( $taxonomy->show_ui ) )
        continue
```

Removing these lines will allow he plugin to display all taxonomies, regardless of whether they are hidden or not.

Props to @helgatheviking for suggesting that plugin in the first place

Comment: @dre Is it possible to add image option in attribute area just above variations?

Answer (score 2):

With the "*Variation Swatches*" plugin (see the answer by @Dre), everything works smoothly, and getting the image is as easy as this:

```
$swatch_term = new WC_Swatch_Term( 'swatches_id', $term_id, $taxonomy, false,
                'swatches_image_size' );

$html = '<img src="' . $swatch_term->thumbnail_src . '" alt=""/>';
```

The "*Taxonomy Images*" has not been updated since WP 3.6.1...

Comment: I want to show the images only with attribute pa_brand and inside loop through all and print it's child images i.e Gucci brand and it's image. is it possible?

Comment: site crashed after adding the code

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla - The post is from 2015. Things might have changed since.

Comment: @tivnet ok got it. I have fixed the issue and added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Technically a WooCommerce "attribute" is just a WordPress Custom Taxonomy. Therefore I would try something like the [Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin.

Comment: Actually, WC product attributes are in a completely separate table from the other taxonomies, so unfortunately plugins like Taxonomy Images completely ignore product attributes. I've just started trying to solve this issue, so if I have any success I'll post some updates.

Comment: UPDATE: I'll eat my hat! I was mistaken - WC *does add them as regular taxonomies,* but it prefixes all the slugs with 'pa_' *and* creates a separate table to keep track of it all. You can use the plugin mentioned, but have to make an alteration to it. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Variation Swatches and Photos extension" plugin is premium and no body would like to purchase that to serve such a purpose as getting an icon image for a brand.

The "Taxonomy Images" has not been updated since WP 3.6.1...

What I came up with is [Category and Taxonomy Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-image/) and that does the job.

Here's how you can get the image URL:

```
    if (function_exists('get_wp_term_image'))
    {
        $meta_image = get_wp_term_image($term_id); 
        //It will give category/term image url 
    }

    echo $meta_image; // category/term image url
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue. Actually i was not passing the right value in taxonomy. I was using variation swatches plugin so was not know which value to pass for taxonomy. below is the working code. I was trying to fetch "brands" attributes list with images.

```
$attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
$taxonomy_terms = array();

if ($attribute_taxonomies) :
    foreach ($attribute_taxonomies as $tax) :
        if (taxonomy_exists(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name))) :
            
            if($tax->attribute_name=="brands"){
                $taxonomy_terms[$tax->attribute_name] = get_terms(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name), 'number=6&orderby=name&hide_empty=1');
            }
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;

foreach ($taxonomy_terms as $item) :
    foreach($item as $child):
        //print_r($child);
         $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $child->term_id, 'product_pa_brands', true );
        $textureImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id );
       

//we are getting image in $textureImg[0]

        }
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```