# Get WooCommerce attribute thumbnail URL by attribute ID (WooCommerce Product Search plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've already spent a couple of hours googling and already tried many things. The closer I could get to my solution was using this code:

```
// With this I successfully get an Array with attribute ID
$carimg_attr = wc_get_product_terms( get_the_id(), 'pa_carimg', 'thumbnail' );

// This echo actually returns the correct ID
echo $carimg_attr[0]->term_id;

// In this echo, I get it empty but this was supposed to show me metas from the attribute (at least as far as other online answers was saying)
echo get_woocommerce_term_meta( $carimg_attr[0]->term_id, 'pa_carimg', true );

// Printing this one, I get actually all fields EXCEPT the one I need: thumbnail
print_r(wc_get_product_terms( get_the_id(), 'pa_carimg', array( 'fields' => 'all' ) ));

// This was just a last desperate try and doesn't work either
$carimg_Img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $carimg_attr[0]->term_id ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $carimg_Img[0]; ?>">
```

I'm just out of ideas! :(

**EDIT:**

I was just being dumb here! Thanks to @LoicTheAztec comment I just noticed this is something from official WooCommerce Product Search plugin.

Comment: Sorry but Woocommerce attributes doesn't have any thumbnail.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec No way! I can't believe how dumb I was! :o Of course, this is a modification of the theme I am using! Hehehe. Oh man, I feel so bad right now.

Comment: Don't feel bad… It is very easy to get loosed and everyone has been in this case once.

Comment: It seems that it's actually from the official WooCommerce Product Search plugin. Googling once more! This time should be easier. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem:

```
<?php
$carimg_attr = wc_get_product_terms( get_the_id(), 'pa_carimg', 'thumbnail' );
$imgAtt_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $carimg_attr[0]->term_id, 'product_search_image_id', true );
$imgAtt_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imgAtt_id, 'medium', false );
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imgAtt_url[0]; ?>">
```

Comment: not worked in my case

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla I can try to help you if you explain your case.

Comment: THank you pedro. i have fixed it and posted my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401124/how-to-add-attribute-terms-image-in-woocommerce
THere was wrong taxonomy i was using